# Printer Stylesheet in Head

Tags: css, printing, print-style

I have a print stylesheet setup but I need to override a few properties of the stylesheet on one page. The easiest way I could figure to do this is to just put the styles needed in the head of the page like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  /* Print Styles */
</style>
```

But my problem is I do not know how to target just the printer.

Note: I *do not* want to create another stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media print {
   .someclass {
        color: red; /*makes it red only when printing*/
   }
   /*more printer-only styles*/
}
```

For reference about other media types: [little link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html).

Comment: I knew it was something like that just could not get my head to remember. Thanks!